# Why sources.list is empty by default on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu

I recently installed Ubuntu Server 13.04 and found an empty sources.list. Though I got a usable sources.list (from a Ubuntu forum), but I wonder why on Earth Ubuntu Server likes to have an empty one by default? Don't they expect users to install more stuff once the OS is setup?

Comment: Is `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` also empty?

Comment: yes, /etc/apt/sources.list.d is empty.

Comment: care to share the sources.list you got from the forum? In my case, this is a fresh install for Ubuntu Server 13.10. Empty sources list except entries from the cdrom. Weirdest thing ever!

Comment: @JasonNathan: I cannot recall from where I got the sources.list but you can probably generate it yourself using: http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/. Anyways, I have now switched to Debian which seems much more stable and less confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen an empty sources.list myself, but it is clearly not expected behaviour. I see two possibilities:

- You upgraded from a previous release, and upgrading the config file failed (look for other `/etc/apt/sources.list` with extensions like `.dpkg-new`)
- In addition to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, APT will automatically use sources found in files in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` - are the entries in here for some reason?

Comment: For Ubuntu desktop, I haven't seen an empty sources.list either. But for some reason, Ubuntu Server gives an empty one (or containing useless entry for CDROM), and yes /etc/apt/sources.list.d is also empty.